# File handling program not working as expected in C

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io

```
FILE *mails;
FILE *tempmails;
mails = fopen("mailer.txt", "r");
tempmails = fopen ("tempmailer.txt" , "a+");
char line[200],templine[200];
char blnklne[]="\n";        
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, mails) != NULL)
{       
    int flag=0;    
    while(fgets(templine, sizeof line, tempmails) != NULL)
    {               
        if((strcmp(line,templine)==0) || (strcmp(line,blnklne)==0))
        {               
            flag = 1;               
        }               
    }           
    if(flag == 0)
    {           
        fputs(line, tempmails);             
    }       
}       
fclose(mails);
fclose(tempmails);
tempmails = fopen ("tempmailer.txt", "r");
remove("mailer.txt");
FILE *newmails;
newmails = fopen("mailer.txt", "a");
while(fgets(templine, sizeof line, tempmails) != NULL)
{       
    fputs(templine, newmails);      
}       
fclose(newmails);
fclose(tempmails);
remove("tempmailer.txt");
```

I have written the above C code for the following purposes:

1. Have to read each line from `mailer.txt` and check if a line is blank or repeated and if both conditions are false have to enter it to a temp file `tempmailer.txt`
2. Remove the file `mailer.txt` and then create a new one and copy enter it into the new file one by one and then remove `tempmailer.txt`.

But on running what actually happens is:

1. Copies from `mailer.txt` to `tempmailer.txt` ALL the lines irrespective of any conditions given(undesired)
2. Deletes `mailer.txt` and creates a new `mailer.txt`(desired)
3. Copies from `tempmailer.txt` to the new file as such(desired)
4. Deletes `tempmailer.txt`(desired)

Whatever I do, I can't erradicate this problem. The OS is linux. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code, it's almost unreadable!

Comment: Why are you comparing `line` (from mailer.txt) to a blank line for each and every line from tempmailer.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset `tempmails` to the beginning of the file before starting each 2nd loop.

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, mails) != NULL)
{
    int flag=0;
    rewind(tempmails);                              /* go back to the begining */
    while(fgets(templine, sizeof line, tempmails) != NULL)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooops.. didn't mean to delete that!

Comment: You need to break when the flag is set to 1 as well to avoid missing duplicates

Comment: @JonCage: breaking "only" prevents extra unneeded work to be done: failure to break after setting `flag` doesn't generate wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to seek to the beginning of the file before the second while loop.

As it stands, your second while loop will never find any matching lines because it will always be pointed to the end of the file.

Comment: +1 for undeleting the answer: I thought you were maybe improving it and waited a while before posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The repeat-detection code is very strange, it's reading from both files at the same time. You can't read from a file opened for append. Try mode `a+`.

This is solvable with a trivial shell script, do you really have to write it in C?

Comment: It is `a+` I have used, not `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this part of code is the reason why you got your question 1

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, mails) != NULL)
{       
     int flag=0;    
     while(fgets(templine, sizeof line, tempmails) != NULL)
    {               
        if((strcmp(line,templine)==0) || (strcmp(line,blnklne)==0))
       {               
            flag = 1;               /* this part may be not correct */
        }               
    }           
    if(flag == 0)
    {           
        fputs(line, tempmails);             
    }       
}
```

If the program finds a line that makes if condition true, then the flag is set to 1, but next line maybe not make if condition true, and you program can not set the flag to 0.So you will never put the mismatch lines which are after the the matched line into the tempmails.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This is not really an answer, but can definitely aid in debugging!*

After the following lines, you should check if the pointers are NULL or not:

```
mails = fopen("mailer.txt", "r");
tempmails = fopen ("tempmailer.txt" , "a+");

if (mails == NULL) printf("Error: could not open file");
if (tempmails == NULL) printf("Error: could not open file");
```

Now you can at least know if it can open and read the files.  To check whether `fgets` works, and isn't giving you errors, use `ferror` or `feof`.

You should add the same NULL checks for every time you call `fopen` on a FILE handle.

Comment: Both files have successfully opened. Otherwise how is the reading and writting happening? Only the conditions are not satisfying.